# Commutative property of matrix multiplication in the algebra of polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, polynomials

I was reading the chapter Polynomial from the book Linear Algebra by Hoffman and Kunze,

In the book, polynomial $F[x]$ was defined as a subspace of $F^{\infty}$ (spanned by $x$, $x^2, ...$ with $x^k = (0,...,1,0,...$) the $1$ in the k-th entry). And they also defined the multiplication as in normal polynomial functions: 
$$(fg)_{i}=\sum_{j=0}^{i} (f)_{j}(g)_{i-j}$$

where $f=(f_{1},f_{2},...)$ and $g=(g_{1},g_{2},...)$, $f,g \in F[x]$.
It was also shown in the book that this implies that $fg$ = $gf$. Now, they also defined:

[image]

Also, the theorems:

[image]

But now this means that $g(\alpha)f(\alpha)=(gf)(\alpha)=(fg)(\alpha)=f(\alpha)g(\alpha)$. Since the linear algebra is not necessarily commutative, we cannot always have that as true right?

For example, if we take the linear algebra as the space of n x n matrix over $R^{1}$, which is a linear algebra with identity but not commutative $(n\geq 2)$. And we also define $f = x $ and $g = x + 2$, we know generally it is not true that $f(A)g(A) = g(A)f(A)$ since matrix multiplication is not commutative, but this property was implied by the definitions.
Am I missing something? would you please kindly point it out? Thank you !

Comment: There is no contradiction here, plus, you've had a very clear idea of why polynomials of matrices always commute.

Comment: @Azif00 Which idea are you talking about here?

Comment: $g(A)f(A)=(gf)(A)=(fg)(A)=f(A)g(A)$.

Comment: @Azif00 Ah I see, you are right, the proof is ok, it was just hard to justify it intuitively, but I realized my mistake, thank you for pointing out the right idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that the algebra need not be commutative, but we don't need the full strength of commutativity to know that $f(\alpha)$ and $g(\alpha)$ commute. Consider, indeed, your example of $f = x + 2$, $g = x$. Then $f(A) g(A) = (A + 2) A = A^2 + 2A$. On the other hand, $g(A) f(A) = A (A + 2) = A^2 + A \cdot 2$. However, $A \cdot 2 = 2A$, so $f(A) g(A) = g(A) f(A)$. Here, we used the fact that $A$ commuted with itself and with scalars in $F$. Indeed, these two facts are enough to explain in general why $f(\alpha)$ and $g(\alpha)$ commute. Both are sums of scalar minutes multiples of powers of $\alpha$. Powers of $\alpha$ commute with each other and with scalar multiples, so $f(\alpha)$ and $g(\alpha)$ will commute.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I get it now. I thought that we actually assumed the commutative property of the polynomials in the proof, whereas we did not. Sorry I unconsciously mixed up $x$ as with scalars in polynomial functions.